# Monotouch - Error setting AVAssetWriterInput - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xamarin.ios, avassetwriter

When I try to set the audio configuration writer input I'm getting an error:

`-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbcdab0`

My code:

```cs
        NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
        {    
            NSNumber.FromFloat(44100.0f),
            NSNumber.FromInt32((int)MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC),
            NSNumber.FromInt32(2),
            NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AVAudioQuality.Medium)
        };
        //Set up the NSObject Array of keys that will be combined with the values to make the NSDictionary
        NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
        {
            AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVChannelLayoutKey
        };          
        //Set Settings with the Values and Keys to create the NSDictionary
        NSDictionary audiosettings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (values, keys);

        writeraudioInput = new AVAssetWriterInput (AVMediaType.Audio, audiosettings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're setting key to `AVChannelLayoutKey` and value to type of `AVAudioQuality`. They're no corresponding to each other. `AVChannelLayoutKey`'s value should contant struct of [AudioChannelLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AudioChannelLayout).

Comment both last key and last values. Or fill and pass `AudioChannelLayout` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the loosely typed NSDictionary-based API.

You could avoid these errors in the future if you use the other constructor that takes an AudioSettings parameter, which conveniently provides intellisense for you.